# setState is not updating React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I am trying to get state from one component, but somewhy I can't see any changes when I do setState(). Here is my state:

```
class MyTestComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        check: 'String1'
    }
   this.testOtherFunction = this.testOtherFunction.bind(this);
}
```

Now, here is the function itself:

```
   testOtherFunction(){
            this.setState({check: "String2"},
            function(){
               console.log(this.state.check, 'total'); // somewhy is not printed
            });
      return this.state.check;
  }
```

And here, in another component I call this function:

```
componentDidMount() {

 console.log("test", MyTestComponent.testOtherFunction()) // returns String1
  }
```

Why it returning old state from a constructor? And how can I fix that? I know setState is async, but I wonder what is the way out from situations like this.

Comment: What exactly want you achieve by calling the method inside MyTestComponent from other component?  I just tried calling your method using a Button inside MyTestComponent and is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

`setState()` does not immediately mutate this.state. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value. That is why you may not see the new value immediately.

you can use setState with callback function.

```
this.setState({check: "String2"},, function () {
    console.log(this.state.check, 'total');
});
```

Comment: Are you saying the callback is the **third** parameter of setState in react native ? I wasn't able to use the callback in my project, that would explain it. (Cannot find the signature in the doc)

Comment: It's the argument and not the third one to add a callback that will called after setState finished.